# Subtract two cells based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, calculated-field

I'm trying to calculate a daily count, given that I have current date, city, and total count.

For each row, I imagine [city's current total] - [the previous total for that city] = the daily count.

Not all cities exist in every date. The number of rows may vary between dates for each city.

I've tried INDEX and MATCH with VLOOKUP, but don't Excel functions well enough.

I'm familiar with arrays, but can't figure how to pluck the UBOUND and UBOUND-1 counts based on the date + city criteria. Ideas?

[image: Spreadsheet illustrating the data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In E2204 put:

```
=D2204-INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($D$1:$D2203)/($C$1:$C2203=C2204),1))
```

OR if one has the formula XLOOKUP:

```
=D2204 - XLOOKUP(C2204,$C$1:$C2203,$D$1:$D2203,0,0,-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm getting a #VALUE! error. Sadly, no XLOOKUP option. Should release to me in a few months.

Comment: Wow! That did the trick. Also, this appears to work `=D2204-INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(14,0,ROW($D$1:$D2203)*($C$1:$C2203=C2204),1))`, though I don't understand what's going on by dividing or multiplying the row function. Appreciate the help!